# Calculate the sum of the numbers separated by a comma in a dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I am trying to calculate the sum of all the numbers separated by a comma in a dataframe column however I keep getting error. This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
Description  scores
logo    
graphics    
eyewear      0.360740,-0.000758
glasses      0.360740,-0.000758
picture      -0.000646
tutorial     0.001007,0.000968,0.000929,0.000889 
computer     0.852264  0.001007,0.000968,0.000929,0.000889
```

This is what the code looks like

```
test['Sum'] = test['scores'].apply(lambda x: sum(map(float, x.split(','))))
```

However I keep getting the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I though it could it be because of missing values at the start of the dataframe. But I subset the dataframe to exclude the missing the values, still I get the same error.

Output

```
Description  scores                                               SUM
logo    
graphics    
eyewear      0.360740,-0.000758                                0.359982
glasses      0.360740,-0.000758                                0.359982
picture      -0.000646                                        -0.000646
tutorial     0.001007,0.000968,0.000929,0.000889               0.003793
computer     0.852264  0.001007,0.000968,0.000929,0.000889     0.856057
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times when using Python seems to be very effective, this might be one of those.

```
df['scores'].apply(lambda x: sum(float(i) if len(x) > 0 else np.nan for i in x.split(',')))

0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.359982
3    0.359982
4   -0.000646
5    0.003793
6    0.856057
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply that helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `str.split`

```
df.scores.str.split(',',expand=True).astype(float).sum(1).mask(df.scores.isnull())
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.359982
3    0.359982
4   -0.000646
5    0.003793
6    0.856057
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The output should be that there should be blanks/missing values for first two rows. I have updated the output data frame in the question

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, I am sure this would have worked at your end, not sure why it is not working on y dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using explode, groupby and sum functions:

```
df.scores.str.split(',').explode().astype(float).groupby(level=0).sum(min_count=1)
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.359982
3    0.359982
4   -0.000646
5    0.003793
6    0.856057
Name: scores, dtype: float64
```

Or to make @WeNYoBen's answer slightly shorter":

```
df.scores.str.split(',',expand=True).astype(float).sum(1, min_count=1)
```